# How do I generate a dynamic XML page using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, apache-flex

I have a function that outputs an XML string:

```
<expensesAC>
  <cashflow>
    <month>6</month>
    <cash>300</cash>
    <projected>null</projected>
  </cashflow>
  <cashflow>
    <month>6</month>
    <cash>300</cash>
    <projected>null</projected>
  </cashflow>
  <cashflow>
    <month>6</month>
    <cash>300</cash>
    <projected>null</projected>
  </cashflow>
</expensesAC>
```

I have a view called `genxml.xml.erb`, and a redirect to `mysite.com:3000/genxml.xml`.

I need this because flex requires an XML file to be passed. However, what I get is:

```
<body>
<expensesAC>
  <cashflow>
    <month>6</month>
    <cash>300</cash>
    <projected>null</projected>
  </cashflow>
</expensesAC>
  <cashflow>
    <month>6</month>
    <cash>300</cash>
    <projected>null</projected>
  </cashflow>
  <cashflow>
    <month>6</month>
    <cash>300</cash>
    <projected>null</projected>
  </cashflow>
</body>
```

So, basically, Rails forces my XML string to be HTML.

How do I generate a dynamic XML page using my string? Or, how do I turn my XML string into an XML page that is dynamically generated? I don't want to create static files, these files need to be generated on the fly because the data in the XML sets will be private information for each user.

Comment: That's not HTML, it's XML with a `<body>` root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to write XML files with Rails, you might probably want to switch from ERB to [Builder template handler](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Builder/XmlMarkup.html).

If you are working with ActiveRecord objects, you can also use the handy `:xml` option when specifying rendering option.

```
def index
  @records = Model.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml { render :xml => @records }
  end
end
```

Comment: As @weppos points out make sure you rename `genxml.xml.erb` to `genxml.xml.builder` or `genxml.xml.rxml`

Comment: weppos, you beat me to it, that's the anwser I would have given

Comment: There's nothing wrong with generating XML using ERB (or HAML, or any other templating engine you prefer), though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently doing exactly what you want without a problem. ERB generation of XML is certainly one of the most convenient methods, especially if the output is predominantly the XML template. It also makes it possible to do neat tricks like render partials with collections.

But I know this didn't used to work properly (had to use [builders](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html)), however I can see that at least from Rails 2.3.5 onwards the ERB approach seems to work fine.

e.g.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def genxml
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml 
    end
  end
end
```

Then genxml.xml.erb produces a valid XML file, and you can even do tricks like:

```
<expensesAC>
<%= render :partial => 'expenses/cashflow', :collection => @expenses-%>
</expensesAC>
```

Where expenses/_cashflow.xml.erb is something like:

```
<cashflow>
  <month><%= cashflow.month %></month>
  <cash><%= cashflow.cash %></cash>
  <projected><%= cashflow.projected %></projected>
</cashflow>
```

NB: the interleaved <expensesAC> and <cashflow> in your example may indicate there's another problem lurking in your XML generation logic.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you'll want to render the content as xml. Something like:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml { render :xml => my_function_that_outputs_xml }
  end
end
```

Comment: Where should that funtion be placed at? Can I pass params into that function from inside the format block?